# For loop not executing even when conditions are met

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

The code is supposed to draw graphs taking values from a few  fields I made, everything works fine until it gets to the for loop, for some reason the loop is just completely skipped, I put in an alert() inside the loop to see if the syntax of my commands were not correct, but it didn't throw an alert, as if the for loop doesn't even run, however it should run since the condition would be true, so what would be causing the code to skip?

```
   var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var dN = document.getElementsByName("dName");
        var dV = document.getElementsByName("dValue");
        var titleInput = document.getElementById("titleInput");
        var stitleInput = document.getElementById("stitleInput");



        function blek()    {

            var propRatio = 1;
            dV.forEach(ratioCalc);

            function ratioCalc(val){
                    if(propRatio > (1 / (val.value / 1000))) {
                    propRatio = (1 / (val.value / 1000)) / 100 * 70;
                    }
            }

            ctx.font = "30px 'Roboto Mono'";
            ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.fillText(titleInput.value, 10, 50);
            ctx.font = "24px 'Roboto Mono'";
            ctx.fillText(stitleInput.value, 10, 80);

            for (i = 0; i > dV.length; i++) {
                //This is problem part, the loop doesn't execute at all and there is no console output.
                ctx.fillText(dN[i].value, 10, 133 + (60 * (i+1)));
                ctx.fillRect(200, 100 + (50 * (i+1)) + 10, dV[i].value * propRatio, 50);
                ctx.fillText(dV[i].value, 20 + dV[i].value * propRatio, 133 + (50 * (i+1) + 10));

            }


        }
```

Comment: `i > dV.length` should be `i < dV.length`

Comment: Ah, my bad, looks like I need to pay more attention to details, thanks!